# Adding description to dynamically generated methods in Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection.emit, dynamicmethod

I have used Reflection.Emit to dynamically generate some types and methods.  Everything works fine, but I want to include some descriptive information with the method so that others can use it more easily.  You would normall do this by including this above the method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is my descriptive information
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="paramName1">paramName1 description</param>
    /// <param name="paramName2">paramName2 description</param>
    /// <param name="glTypeFieldReference"></param>
    /// <returns>Information about the return type</returns>
```

Is it possible to include this information with Reflection.Emit, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because that is not part of the IL metadata. Instead, the compiler writes that into the optional .xml file that goes alongside the dll, and `TypeBuilder` etc doesn't handle those in any way. You could of course write the xml file separately - the schema should be available somewhere.

Comment: [Here's](http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/XmlDocumentation.xsd) one guys attempt at creating a schema for it.